# Center flex items on wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have set up a flexbox with two items which should be on the left and right on a normal screen.

If the screen is not big enough to show both next to each other, it should wrap but then they should be centered and not aligned on the left.

I tried different solutions (like using `margin: auto` on the child items) but that aligned them more to the center even when in the same row.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.large {
  width: 500px;
}
.small {
  width: 175px;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 25px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container large">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container small">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SoWhy/zfx4ub8x/

The first container is the intended positioning, the second container emulates the same container on a smaller screen, note the align to the left.

Is there a way to define that the flexbox is to align items differently when wrapped or can I only do it using the "@media screen" method (which requires me to set a certain size and is thus not flexible if the size of the items changes)?

Comment: No, flexbox can't do that..it's a common request.

Answer (score 17):

This may not work in your case, but it's worth mentioning this lesser-known difference between `justify-content: space-between` and `justify-content: space-around`.

From the flexbox specification:

> [**8.2. Axis Alignment: the `justify-content` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#justify-content-property)
>
> The `justify-content` property aligns flex items along the main axis
>   of the current line of the flex container.

There are five values that apply to `justify-content`. Here are two of them:

> ***`space-between`***
>
> Flex items are evenly distributed in the line.
>
> **If the leftover free-space is negative or there is only a single flex item on the line, this value is identical to `flex-start`.**

This explains why your items align left on wrap with `space-between`.

Now look at `space-around`:

> ***`space-around`***
>
> Flex items are evenly distributed in the line, with half-size spaces
>   on either end.
>
> **If the leftover free-space is negative or there is only a single flex item on the line, this value is identical to `center`.**

Hence, to center-align flex items on wrap, consider using `space-around`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; /* ADJUSTMENT */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mxhv1b8p/)

Comment: But using space-around, the items will have "half-size spaces on either end" (according to the explanation you posted). I don't want those spaces, I want the items to be as far apart as possible when not wrapped.

Comment: The 25px margins were just so that they can be better seen in the example. Sorry for the confusion. In the real application, the margins would be "25px 0px", i. e. no margin on left or right

Comment: If there is a hack that does the job, I'm always open to it. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I understand. The purpose of my answer was to reveal the centering feature of `space-around`, in case it helps you or others.

Comment: As @SoWhy said, this answer is just wrong - it works when wrapping, but it does not work when on the same line, as there is extra spacing in between the items and the edges.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done nowadays by setting `justify-content` to `space-evenly`. This option however is not yet included in the Flexbox specification.

Note that I had to add a `column-gap` to adjust the position of the child items, since `space-evenly` introduces extra spaces in the sides.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  column-gap: calc(100% - 2*100px); /* 100px is size of child items */
}
.large {
  width: 500px;
}
.small {
  width: 175px;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 25px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container large">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container small">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the intended result: on the first (wide) container, there is spacing on the outside of items, whereas the author wants items to be as far apart as possible

Comment: @ewen-lbh You are right, I missed that the OP even try to manipulate the margins but didn't wanted to get the child items closer. I corrected the code to account for this.

Answer (score -3):

> **Note: You will have to use media query for different widths .**

No way to detect when it is wrapped using css3.

If you want to center item use `display:inline-flex` and `justify-content: center;` to container and `margin: 0 auto;` to class `item`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end; 
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It wraps when container size is less than 200px.

[Click to see center aligned example in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/monirulalom/gwtw7sgk/2/)

If you want to keep items in single line `flex-wrap: nowrap` - which forces flex items are forced to stay in a single line.

So the style for  `.container` will be like the following.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end; 
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

[Click to see items forced to stay single line in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/monirulalom/hxu59162/)

Comment: I don't want them to stay on a single line. On small devices I do want them wrapped - just differently aligned. Your solutions makes the items smaller

Comment: @SoWhy You will have to use media query for different widths . My answer is updated check now.