# Align two items left and right when on one line, and center when on two lines

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

Let's consider two items **A** and **B** within their container **C**. When `width(C) > width(A)+width(B)`, I want the items to stay on the same line: **A** aligned left and **B** right. But when `width(C) < width(A)+width(B)`, I want them to use their own line, and be centered within **C** horizontally.

I have [achieved](https://jsfiddle.net/33xs28Lx/) all the above except for the latter requirement — centering them when they are on their own line each. How do I do that? Keen to use flexbox but any working solution would be good, even with floats.

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: orange;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Item1 Item1 Item1 Item1 Item1</div>
  <div>Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: May be i don't understand your question but it seems like it's already working to me

Comment: you will need to use media queries, so have a breakpoint at the point that the divs would go onto their own line and set their margin: auto;

Comment: Instead of `justify-content: space-between`, consider `justify-content: space-around`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38290861/3597276

Comment: @Andrewbrough Using media queries with a breakpoint has a couple of cons, see my comment to *maxshuty's* answer.
@Michael_B the items need to be aligned left and right respectively *when they're on the same line*. `space-around` will make them not stick to the edges.

Comment: @Greendrake. yes it the content is not going to be a known width then this makes this not always work.  the only alternative that I could see is using js to calculate when to add/remove the css properties based on the sizes of your containers then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

In this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgLLvxhy/) I made you can see that with the media query it now is centered, and I used Michael_B's suggestion of `justify-content: space-around;` and ended up with this:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

You can play with the pixels for your specific usage.

If they must be on a new line when centered then you'll want to play around with something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgLLvxhy/1/) solution I made, basically just adding `<br class="hidden"/>` and only showing it when the screen is anything <= 768 pixels. Or you can play around with your own solution if [you hold grudges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br) against `<br/>`

Comment: Thanks for that. Your solution is viable but 1) requires to adjust `max-width` whenever the content of *A* or *B* changes; 2) Only works where the container's width is stretched to the browser window; this isn't necessarily the case.