# How to center divs at every breakpoint with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center the divs how I currently have them, but the issue is that when there are two divs they are not aligning with the rectangle above. I know that they would align with `justify-content:space between`, but that would prevent a div from being centered when it is the only one in the row. Is it possible what I want to do?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  /*            flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis*/
  flex: 0 0 31%;
  margin: 0 1% 2% 1%;
  height: 300px;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: blue
}

.col3 {
  background: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .col {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">

  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="col col1">

    </div>
    <div class="col col2">

    </div>
    <div class="col col3">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It may not be a perfect solution, but it may be worth consideration: Use `justify-content: space-around` instead of `space-between`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38290861/3597276

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `margin-left: auto` to the `.col1` and `margin-right: auto` to the `.col2`to push the divs respectively.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  /*            flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis*/
  flex: 0 0 31%;
  margin: 1% 0 2% 0;
  height: 300px;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.col3 {
  background: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .col {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">

  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="col col1">

    </div>
    <div class="col col2">

    </div>
    <div class="col col3">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```