# Flexbox space-between except for rows with single items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs. One needs to sit at the left, one at the right. A parent flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` works perfectly for this, except when the flex items wrap (which they should be able to do). After they wrap, they are left-aligned because there's only two items total.

How can I make rows with single items centre-aligned?

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap">
 <div style="background: orange">
  <strong>Canvas Prints</strong><br>
  <span style="font-size: 14px; color: #ff0000">Create a masterpiece for any wall in your home!</span>
 </div>
 <div style="background: pink">
  <img width="176" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEAPU9xK-mE81DSwYqh_uMb_EUuqXT1yWzIvs9j7diGY-FHh6X">
 </div>
</div>
```

(Or you can use the fiddle, because it's easier to squish the output pane of the fiddle than resize the whole SO window to see the divs wrap: https://jsfiddle.net/xv6oa418/1/)

---

**Additional note:** @KaranTewari suggested adding `flex: 1` to the first child div, but I'd like text in the left div to not wrap until absolutely necessary (specifically, it should start wrapping only after the second flex item has wrapped onto the next line). The second div is actually going to be an image so I've updated my fiddle and snippet to reflect this.

Comment: *"After they wrap, they are left-aligned because there's only two items total."* … Not exactly. They are left aligned because that's what is defined in the spec.

Comment: In case you're able to use `space-around` instead of `space-between`, the solution is very simple: [Center flex items on wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38290861/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B Well yeah, the spec says that if there's one item on a line it should be left aligned, but the only reason that comes into play is because there's two total items and they're on separate lines. That's all I meant. And nah, `space-around` doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I used `flex-grow: 1` on the first/left div, and `margin: auto` on the second/right div. This makes the first div expand to take up all space so the auto margin of the second div doesn't get to do anything. Then when it wraps, the second div is no longer blocked by the first one and the auto margin takes over, centring the second div.

Like so:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap">
 <div style="background: orange; flex-grow: 1;">
  <strong>Canvas Prints</strong><br>
  <span style="font-size: 14px; color: #ff0000">Create a masterpiece for any wall in your home!</span>
 </div>
 <div style="background: pink; margin: auto">
  <img width="176" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEAPU9xK-mE81DSwYqh_uMb_EUuqXT1yWzIvs9j7diGY-FHh6X">
 </div>
</div>
```

(And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xv6oa418/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.text {
  background: orange;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;

}

.text:only-child {
  background-color: green;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <strong>Canvas Prints</strong><br>
    <span >Create a masterpiece for any wall in your home!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img" >
    <img width="176" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEAPU9xK-mE81DSwYqh_uMb_EUuqXT1yWzIvs9j7diGY-FHh6X">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use :only-child selector and give margin:auto to the only-child element. Please see the snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
flex:1
```

This ensures you are using full available space, here jsfiddle edited
https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/tfg0kymb/1/

Comment: This makes no difference. In the fiddle, if you squish the output pane so it's no longer wide enough to fit both divs, the pink one wraps onto the next line. At that point, everything is left-aligned and I want it to be centre-aligned. If I didn't make my question clear enough, let me know and I'll edit it.

Comment: My bad, it didnt got saved last time, here's what i did https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/tfg0kymb/2/

Comment: Ah I see what you did there, but I also want the text in the first div to remain on the one line until absolutely necessary. So your suggestion works, but not quite how I wanted. I'll update my question to mention this.

Comment: Hi, seems like you have used <br> due to which its breaking the line, I've removed the same and reused flex:1, please let me know if this works for you
https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/5qzp4j0n/1/

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that latest fiddle is just completely wrong haha. Never mind, I figured it out and posted my own answer :)