# Centering a justify-content space-between once it becomes a single column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to style a div that has two children, with flexbox and flex-wrap, without media-queries, that at a certain width is space-between, but once it is a single column is centered (as opposed to currently where once it wraps it's like flex-start). Hopefully that makes sense.

I think this is the relevant code, basically when it wraps, i would like space between to become center:

HTML and CSS

```css
.content-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 82%;
}

.content h1 {
    min-width: 20rem;
}

.content h6 {
    min-width: 15.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>'content1'</h1>
        <h6>'content2'</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post the code you tried

Comment: My bad. Obviously any question is way clearer if I include the code. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: This question might already solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290861/center-flex-items-on-wrap

Comment: @Tomas_M any reasons for not using media queries or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this fits your needs.
Since I don't believe that there is a way to solve your problem using only native CSS (i.e. no media queries, and I assume no JS), I let myself change the `space-between` to `space-around` (since you gave `.content` 82% there is not much of a difference).

if you do not want to use `space-around`, I find it hard for me to believe that there is a solution without media-queries \ JS.

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  place-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  width: min-content;
}

h6 {
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="content__1">'content1'</h1>
        <h6 class="content__2">'content2'</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this:

```css
.content-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;

}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 82%;
}

.content h1 {
    min-width: 20rem;

}

.content h6 {
    min-width: 15.5rem;

}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>'content1'</h1>
        <h6>'content2'</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's impossible to achieve what you want the way you want (i.e., CSS without a `@media` query).

#### Solution 1: CSS without a @media query

If you don’t want to use a `@media` query, then look at Solution 1. But `space-around` is a different thing than `space-between` because `space-between` will push your two elements all the way to the left and right when they’re not stacked above each other, while `space-around` will not do so.

An example of `space-between`:

[image: space-between]

An example of `space-around`:

[image: space-around]

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 82%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content h1 {
  min-width: 20rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.content h6 {
  min-width: 15.5rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <h6>Content 2</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

If Solution 1 is good enough for you, then you don’t need to read further. But there are many better options on the table. If you’re not limited and can make changes to your code, then I think you should look at other possible solutions below. You can use different approaches to achieve what you want if you want your two elements to be pushed all the way to the left and right when they’re not stacked above each other.

The reason why this can’t be done without using a `@media` query, JavaScript or jQuery is that CSS on its own can’t “switch” from `space-between` to `space-around` when your two elements get stacked above each other. You need to define some rules using a `@media` query, JavaScript or jQuery so that CSS will change from `space-between` to `space-around` at a specific window width (i.e., exactly when your two elements get stacked above each other). See other possible solutions below.

#### Solution 2: CSS with a @media query

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 82%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content h1 {
  min-width: 20rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.content h6 {
  min-width: 15.5rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 708px) {
  .content {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <h6>Content 2</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution 3: JavaScript

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 709) {
    document.getElementById("content").style.justifyContent = "space-around";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("content").style.justifyContent = "space-between";
  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 709) {
    document.getElementById("content").style.justifyContent = "space-around";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("content").style.justifyContent = "space-between";
  }
}
```

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 82%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content h1 {
  min-width: 20rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.content h6 {
  min-width: 15.5rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content" id="content">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <h6>Content 2</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution 4: jQuery

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 709) {
    $(".content").css("justify-content", "space-around");
  } else {
    $(".content").css("justify-content", "space-between");
  }
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 709) {
    $(".content").css("justify-content", "space-around");
  } else {
    $(".content").css("justify-content", "space-between");
  }
});
```

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 82%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content h1 {
  min-width: 20rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.content h6 {
  min-width: 15.5rem;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <h6>Content 2</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

*P.S. I added `text-align: center;` and `line-height: 50px;` to the `.content` class because if you really want to have your content centered then you also need to center text horizontally and vertically inside your containers. This is a quick fix, you can remove that if you want. Also, `border: 2px solid red;` is added to the `.content` class so you can better understand the difference between `space-between` and `space-around`.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.content-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 82%;
    text-align:center;
}

.content h1 {
    min-width: 20rem;
}

.content h6 {
    min-width: 15.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>'content1'</h1>
        <h6>'content2'</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `clamp()` where I will toggle between a fixed width and full width based on a parameter (`50rem` in this case)

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 82%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content > * {
  width: clamp(15rem, (50rem - 100vw)*9999, 100%);
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>'content1'</h1>
    <h6>'content2'</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related article if you want more detail: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses only flexbox, no media queries or JavaScript. Does this do what you want?

```css
.content-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 82%;
    text-align: center;
}

.content h1,
.content h6 {
    flex: 1;
}

.horizontal-spacing {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: calc(20rem + 15.5rem);
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>'content1'</h1>
        <span class="horizontal-spacing"></span>
        <h6>'content2'</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```