# Flex basis with justify-content not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue with flexbox. So at first I had only two images(without the divs) in a flexbox but I was facing the problem where the images would share one row when I wanted to force two rows, so then I decided to put two divs in whose parent's property was .left div { flex: 1 100% } because I wanted to force them to share their own row, but then I realized that this may have undermined justify-content? Because when I did justify-content: center or justify-content: space-around, nothing changed; I assumed this was because of the flex basis. So the question is how do I force my images(which are still in divs) to be on separate rows and also be able to freely adjust justify-content to whatever attribute I want. From doing it myself just now I think I made it so that the divs are on separate rows(which is what I want), but the only issue now is trying to do justify-content and be able to move the left image; also this issue is occurring regardless of the media query. The rule change is also located at the bottom rule in each media query.

-Thanks

```css
.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    order: 1;
    width: 45%;
}



.middle {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    order: 2;
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
}




.container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 70vh;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5% auto 8% auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.container p {
  
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #nav {
     flex-direction: column; /*updated*/
    margin-bottom: 7%;
    }
    #nav ul {
      padding-left: 0; /*added*/
    }
    #nav li {
      flex: 1 1 100%; /*updated*/
      padding: 5px;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #nav li a{
      
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
      
    }
    
  
     

    #bigwrap {
      width: 100%;

    }
    
    .container {
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      
    }




    .left, .right {
      flex: 1 100%;
    }

   .middle {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    justify-content: center;
   }

   .box {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
   }
   
   #header2{
    
    justify-content: space-around;
    
   }
   
   .left {
    justify-content: center;
    
   }
   
   .left div {
    flex: 1 50%;
    
   }
   
  
  
   


  
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1300px) {
 
  .container {
    width: 90%;
  }
  
    .left div {
    flex: 1 100%;
    
   }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
         <div>            
          <img src="corn.jpg" alt="Picture of kid">            
            </div>
            
            <div>
               <img src="acorns.jpg" alt="Picture of kid">
            </div> 
            
            
           
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="box">
             <h2> Acorns </h2>
             </div>
            
            <div class="box2">
              <p>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. 
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.</p>


            </div>

              <div class="box">
              <p>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. 
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. </p>
              
          </div>
            
            <div class="box">
            <p>This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. 
              This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence. This is a sample sentence.</p>
              


            </div>

        </div>
```

-Thanks

Comment: h2 closing tag issue so two div closing tag error issue maybe  [  https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/xe5ybfwz/  ] i'm not sure take a look at the fiddle

Comment: This may help clarify the behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36487987/3597276

Comment: Thank you for the link but for some reason it still isn't working. I then  made the width of each div 40 percent which would only total 80%, so not sure why justify-content wouldn't work. Ok I have another page just like it and it works perfectly fine so it must have happened when copy pasting or something. I'll do a side by side comparison and check it out, thanks.

Comment: Found it. Kind of embarassing to say here...

Thank you guys for your help