# How can I make the last row of a flex box layout with "space-around" not be centered?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flex box to arrange some equally-sized divs, and I've set `justify-content: space-around`.  This looks great for all the rows except the last one.  I'd like any elements in the last row to be even with the left-most divs in the previous rows.

### This is what it looks like:

[image]

and

[image]

### And this is what I would like:

[image]

and

[image]

#### How can I achieve this?

Currently, I have this CSS:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-around
}

#container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 110px;
}
```

With this HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chrisshroba/q2mm9ccj/

Comment: Maybe something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/q2mm9ccj/1/) will work for you.

Comment: Is the number of divs dynamic? Otherwise, [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) could be of use.

Comment: you can use space-between and for and give margin to container

Comment: @Michael_B Can you explain exactly why this is working?

Comment: @kojow7, Two things: (1) I'm not using `space-around`. I'm using `space-between`, with horizontal padding on the container. (2) Each value is designed to behave differently in the instance described above. See this post for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36487476/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Okay, thank you that makes sense. If you have time please see my latest question. I am wanting to use flexbox (rather than gridbox), need items to line up, but the items are dynamic in size and thus need to match to the largest width.