# Center when only a single item in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox-controlled footer. It can contain 1,2 or 3 subordinate divs.

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

<div class='footer'>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Middle</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

With 2 or 3 **divs**, the css above works fine:

- with three, **Left** and **Right** are flushed left and right and **Middle** is in the middle.
- with 2 they are flushed left and right

But with a single **div**, it is left-justified. I would prefer it would be centered.

How can I adjust the css so that in the case of a single **div** it will be centered, while retaining the behaviour for 2 or 3 **divs**?

Comment: For anybody not needing `space-between`, `space-around` centers a single item by design [(jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fx6pw1hd/)). Here's the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36487476/3597276

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
.footer > :only-child
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use ```margin: auto``` ?

Comment: It was in the initial answer. But as it was noted in the comments (and then removed), you'd better not overwrite rules when you don't need to.

Answer (score 5):

you can make sure your items grow with the available space so their content will be located relatively to the item

```
.footer > div {
   flex-grow:1:
   text-align: center; // for example
}
```

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer > div {
 flex-grow:1;
 text-align:center; //for example
}
```

```html
<div class='footer'>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Middle</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the margin to just do that, adjust margin, you can use `space-evenly`, or the cross browsers trick with pseudo elements and your existing `space-between`

Stack snippet - *pseudo* + `space-between`

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.footer::before, .footer::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class='footer'>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Middle</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Stack snippet - `space-evenly` ([browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content))

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class='footer'>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Middle</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```