# Flexbox space-between but center if one element

Tags: css, flexbox

I've the following HTML and CSS.

```
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container-box {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;
  margin:50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #9009A0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Which gives this layout:

[image: CSS layout]

The first layout for multiple items does what I expect, but how can I change the second to position the element in center as it only has one element?

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/dennismadsen/pen/oNvqjjV

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For cases where you have one item in the container, you can use the `:only-child` pseudo-class.

Add this to your code:

```
.box:only-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.container-box {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #9009A0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box:only-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

In such cases, flex `auto` margins will override `justify-content` because:

> [§ 8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

---

More about `:only-child`:

> [§ 6.6.5.10. `:only-child`
>   pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#only-child-pseudo)
>
> The `:only-child` pseudo-class represents an element that has no
>   siblings. Same as `:first-child:last-child` or
>   `:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)`, but with a lower specificity.

---

More about flex `auto` margins:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

---

Also, to spotlight some interesting flex behavior, if you were using `space-around` instead of `space-between`, you wouldn't need `auto` margins.

- [Flex item should align left, not center, when it wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36487476/3597276)

Comment: This doesn't work if there are elements in the container that are hidden with `display: none`

Comment: @GrantHumphries, that's right, because `display: none` doesn't remove the element as a sibling in the HTML. But there may be another solution. Post a demo here or a new question.

Comment: How to do it when the second element is only hidden by `display: none;` ?

Answer (score 2):

For info, You could also use together `:first-child` and `:last-child` if you wanted to mind about very old browsers   ;)

```css
.container-box {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #9009A0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.container-box .box:first-child:last-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different idea with only margin:

```css
.container-box {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 30px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #9009A0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

If you will have more than 3 elements you can add an extra rule

```css
.container-box {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 30px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #9009A0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
  margin:auto;
}

.box:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```